# Cassandra Nodes not linking in Docker

Tags: docker, cassandra

I am watching a kind of old video on PluralSight for Cassandra and linking works with the method below. However, it is not working with the current docker version. This is how I am linking different nodes. For example:

```
docker run --name=n1 -d tobert/cassandra
docker run --name n2 -d tobert/cassandra -seeds 172.17.0.7
```

172.17.0.7 is the IP address when I run the command

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' n1
```

However, only one node is allowed to run at a time is seems. When I run the command

```
docker ps
```

or

```
docker exec -it n1 nodetool status
```

only one of the containers are running. When I try to inspect a container's ip address, it returns empty. Is there another way to link cassandra nodes in docker?

Comment: Running through the same course, I hit the exact same issue. Running on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Manage to resolve this.
It appears to have been an issue with the docker machine created by the "Docker quickstart terminal". Perhaps related to default memory of 1024?

Recreating the machine solved it for me

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory=4096 default
```

Comment: I don't have a default machine and tried to execute the same command, failed with the error : "Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path""

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Dashu is right, you need more than the default memory to run multiple Cassandra instances.  See similar Twitter thread here: https://twitter.com/perksc/status/641159044225466368.

The `-seeds` parameter is specific to the entrypoint of this Cassandra docker container and facilitates Cassandra's own clustering (see Github project here: https://github.com/tobert/cassandra-docker).  With this feature you don't need to use Docker's own container linking to establish a cluster.

(I'm the author of the Pluralsight course in question.  Funny that the course is less than a year old, but so much has changed in Docker since then!)

Comment: Dear Paul O'Fallon I've come to here while watching your Pluralsight course about Cassandra. Still cannot link the second Cassandra node to the first one. BTW, I'm using windows 10. I can't take a look to the twitter thread you have provided, because the tweets are protected. Any other source/link for solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. It is solved with using the memory parameter `-m 4g`. So I initialize the nodes with 4 g.

#### A - Changing The Docker Memory

And it is good to increase the Docker Memory;

[image]

#### B - My Setup

Windows Version: Windows 10 Pro
Memory: 16 gb
Docker version;

```
docker --version
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

#### C - Solution Demo

Initializing 1st cassandra node;

```
docker run --name=n1 -d -m 4g tobert/cassandra
```

Getting the ip of the first node;

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" n1
```

The output of the above command is;

```
172.17.0.3
```

Initializing the second Cassandra node linking with the first one;

```
docker run --name n2 -d -m 4g tobert/cassandra -seeds 172.17.0.3
```

Running the **nodetools status** command at first node;

```
docker exec -it n1 nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.0.3  51.5 KB    256     100.0%            002150d0-90b9-4f8f-861f-0d0205e3ea72  rack1
UN  172.17.0.4  82.46 KB   256     100.0%            05c06381-778e-4989-860b-756d05c8cfbc  rack1
```

Running the **nodetools status** command at second node;

```
docker exec -it n2 nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.0.3  51.5 KB    256     100.0%            002150d0-90b9-4f8f-861f-0d0205e3ea72  rack1
UN  172.17.0.4  82.46 KB   256     100.0%            05c06381-778e-4989-860b-756d05c8cfbc  rack1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link docker containers with --link flag:

```
docker run --name n1 tobert/cassandra
docker run --name n2 --link n1:cassandra tobert/cassandra -seeds cassandra
```

[Communication across links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links:0e5ffdcdfe9fe23174931bb91e4a2fba), from docker documentation, contains detailed explanation how to use --link flag.

---

I also run your commands and it works on my machine.

Below is output of the command: `docker exec -it n1 nodetool status`:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.0.3  72 KB      256     100.0%            f0a34a45-5f7a-46ff-8fe6-1cf5ff36a3e3  rack1
UN  172.17.0.2  51.46 KB   256     100.0%            8036177e-515c-42b1-9263-3b815c25bde6  rack1
```

Also, when -seed parameter is wrong (not existing ip address) second container is waiting for a while and after ~30s terminates with exeception:

```
ERROR [main] 2016-02-07 19:12:11,081 CassandraDaemon.java:541 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1307) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:533) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
```

So I think n2 is not able to access n1 - please double check your n1 ip address (to check your n2 logs run: `docker exec xxxx  tail -f /data/log/system.log -n 100`, where xxxx - n2 container id).

If you do not have any specific requirements on Cassandra version you can also check image from official repository: https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/.